# React Paginate, hide right pagination links after break and before next link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate) library and it works great.

I don't see a way to only show the right links. Something like this:
[image] as apposed to the default: [image]

It's just a small little detail that I would like to accomplish in my app but I see no way to do this with the current api.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

Ah. Setting `marginPagesDisplayed={0}` does exactly what I want. It's not very clear from the documentation so I had to do some little trial and error.

here's what I came up with:

```
       <ReactPaginate
        forcePage={currentPage} 
        previousLabel={"previous"}
        nextLabel={"next"}
        breakLabel={<a href="">...</a>}
        pageCount={this.props.total_count}
        marginPagesDisplayed={0}
        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
        onPageChange={}//handle page change event
        containerClassName={"pagination"}
        subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
        activeClassName={"active"} 
      />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how to change name of previous and next labels.